# what is the difference between these declarations?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *const ptr1;
//and
const int* ptr2;
//and
int const* ptr3;
```

I was studying refrences so I heard about const pointers as a result I decided to create one, however only ptr1 resulted in const pointer and I can't understand the difference.

Comment: [this might help](https://cdecl.org/)

Comment: @Zolo_Ryan You forgot to mention also the following declaration const signed  const int const * const  ptr4; .:)